# flash, how to call an external javascript on frame action/change

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-2

i have a flash movie with 2 frames.
and i would like to call an external javasscript function on frame action.

to call it from a button i can use:

```
on (release) {
getURL("javascript:OpenMe();");
}
```

but i don't know ho to do it on frame action, maybe on frame load...

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add code directly to a keyframe on the timeline.  On your keyframe just put:

```
getURL("javascript:OpenMe();");
```

That said, this is not the recommended way to call JavaScript from Flash.  You should be using the [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001036.html#249612) class.  The same call with ExternalInterface would look like this:

```
if(ExternalInterface.available) ExternalInterface.call("OpenMe");
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a movieclip with _visible set to false, and then place that inside as

```
onLoad = function(){getURL("javascript:OpenMe();");
```

That way, you can edit the functionality in one place and it will edit both. It also ensure that it happens `onLoad` and not before (meaning that it will happen after everything on the timeline).

As a side note, [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001036.html#249612) is generally suggested as the preferred way to us JS in AS, especially since it is future compatible.